# Fast File transfer

Tags: zeromq

What are the different options available for fast file transfer? I know fast is relative term. Basically one of the component(Tibco)  is used to transfer the files(as large as 500MB) from our local folder to client folder(B2B zone). This component internally uses SFTP protocol and we found the implementation its quite slow(It takes 3/4 Hrs). 
What are the alternatives to it ? 
1)Can Zero MQ be used to transfer the files?
2)Tibco has one more product- Managed File Transfer which internally uses RocketStream protocol(http://support.rocketstream.com/docs/RS12/server/index.html?the_rocketstream_protocols.html) which they claim is super fast.
3)Can Apache Camel(FTP component) be used in such cases?
Latency and security are the main concerns.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at the ZeroMQ FileMQ project, it may fit your needs (https://github.com/zeromq/filemq)